# Reference request: Representation Theory of Indefinite Orthogonal Lie Group and its Lie Algebra

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, book-recommendation

In most textbooks, I have seen material on representation theory of the orthogonal group and its Lie algebra, and at most of the Lorentz group. However, I haven't seen any references talking about the representation theory of the general indefinite orthogonal group and its Lie algebra. Are there any such references at all?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234729/representation-theory-of-sop-q

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139110/what-is-the-lie-algebra-of-the-indefinite-orthogonal-group

Comment: Basic Algebra
By：Anthony W. Knapp

Comment: @C.F.G that doesn't have any material on indefinite orthogonal group.

Comment: At least on the Lie algebra level, all $\mathfrak{so}(p,q)$ have complexification $\simeq \mathfrak{so}_{p+q}(\mathbb C)$. Via the correspondence of complex representations of a Lie algebra and those of its complexification, this means that a lot of their representation theory will be "isomorphic" too, confer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3258221/96384. As discussed there, one notable exception, where each $\mathfrak{so}(p,q)$ will be a bit different, is when it comes to which representations are conjugate to which. For that, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3738143/96384.